# Which packages should I install on Cygwin to use simpleScalar - Alpha configuration?

Tags: linux, cygwin, simulation

I already installed the following packages version 4.3-1, gcc-core version 11.3.0-1, gcc-g++ version 11.3.0-1. However, when I run the make command after running the make config-alpha command, I get several errors on the screen. I already tried to install other versions of these packages but I still get the same results.[errors that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aJxQ.png)

Which other additional package should I install?

Comment: cygwin programs need to be configured as `linux`, not windows. That should cause `#include <dirent.h>` to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SimpleScalar is the one here:

[https://www.es.ele.tue.nl/~yhe/aca/Simplescalar_Download.html](https://www.es.ele.tue.nl/%7Eyhe/aca/Simplescalar_Download.html)

the packaging is ancient (gcc gcc-2.7.2.3) and its manually crafted configure is not considering any recent platforms.

It seems very hard to adjust to a Cygwin build and you can not use the GCC Cygwin compiler for a cross build of a Alpha platform